# Append date to a filename in linux

Tags: linux, shell, timestamp

I want add the date next to a filename ("somefile.txt"). For example: somefile_DDMMYYYYHHMMSS.txt

Maybe a script will do or some command in the terminal window. I'm using Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
a=somefile.txt
bname="${a%.*}"
ename="${a##*.}"
date=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
echo ${bname}_${date}.${ename}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

## This code will list all files in the current directory and renames all the files to specified format.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
TDATE=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
for FULLFILE in `ls`
do
FILENAME=`echo $FULLFILE | cut -d '.' -f1`
EXTN=`echo $FULLFILE | cut -d '.' -f2`
mv ${FULLFILE} ${FILENAME}_${TDATE}.${EXTN}
done
```